# lazarus gdb internal error

Tags: macos, gdb, freepascal, lazarus

I am running a program in lazarus and gdb is terminating the process with below error.

I have installed the gdb version 7.8.1 on osx 10.10.1 using this link http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/GDB_on_OS_X_Mavericks_and_Xcode_5

```
While executing the command:
"TGDBMIDebuggerInstruction: "-file-exec-and-symbols ", "
gdb reported:
"&"solib-target.c:326: internal-error: void solib_target_free_so(struct so_list *): Assertion        `so->lm_info->name == NULL' failed.\nA problem internal to GDB has been detected,\nfurther      debugging may prove unreliable.""

The GDB command:
"-file-exec-and-symbols "
did not return any result.

The GDB process is no longer running.
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

> solib-target.c:326: internal-error

That is a GDB bug.

You should try to verify that it is still present in GDB trunk, and report it in GDB [Bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla).